¿Cómo exportar valor obtenido en un listener de un archivo js a otro?
Tengo 2 archivos js. En el primero (index.js) capturo en un listener de un botón el texto digitado en un input y lo guardo en la variable texto (esta variable es la que quiero exportar):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
    <title>Hoja 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <h1>hoja 1</h1>
        <input type="text" class="campo" id="campo">
        <button class="boton" id="boton">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  <script src="./index.js" type="module"></script> 
</body>
</html>

index.js
const campo = document.getElementById("campo");
const boton= document.getElementById("boton");
let texto

boton.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    texto = campo.value;
    window.location.href="home.html";
});

export {texto};

en el mismo listener se envía a la página home.html y desde mi segundo archivo (home.js) intento importar la variable texto pero me aparece el siguiente error:

index.js:5 
Uncaught 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
   at index.js:5:7


home.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./home.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title" id="titulo">hola</h1>
    </div>
 <script src="./home.js" type="module"></script>   
</body>
</html>

home.js
import {texto} from "./index.js";
console.log(texto);

const titulo = document.getElementById('titulo');
titulo.textContent = texto;

Si hago la exportación desde un archivo que no tiene addEventListener funciona perfecto, pero en este caso es necesario.

Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour]. ¿qué es lo que quieres lograr con esto?. Pregunto porque pienso que la respuesta correcta depende de qué es lo que persigues.

Tienes 2 páginas index.html y home.html, ellas son independientes y están separadas. Cuando navegas, comienza todo desde cero aun cuando estes en el mismo sitio. Es decir, todas las variables almacenadas en memoria se pierden. Por lo que planteas nunca va a funcionar.
Debes implementar un mecanismo para almacenar la variable o para pasarla a la otra página, por ejemplo usando localStorage
Guardas en el index.js
boton.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    localStorage.setItem("texto", campo.value);
    window.location.href="home.html";
});

Y en home.js lo rescatas
titulo.textContent = localStorage.getItem("texto") || "texto default";


Muchas Gracias soy nuevo en el tema y llevo varios dias rompiendome la cabeza con esto. Una cosa más, que tan recomendable es el uso localStorage para datos sensibles?

@DesInbytech El localStorage guarda sin encriptar (a menos que tu implementes un método) cualquier persona con acceso (y con poco conocimiento) podrá ver lo almacenado. Por otro lado, ningún otro sitio puede acceder al localStorage cosa que no sucede con las cookies por lo que si tiene algún grado de seguridad. Todo dependerá de que tan sensible sea los datos, yo no guardaría nunca la contraseña, pero no veo problema en guardar el nombre del usuario

Entiendo... Muchas muchas gracias @Yussef por todo el apoyo
